# How to vimgrep swap files in a directory

Tags: vim, terminal

I accidentally closed a terminal window which had some vim tabs were open.

Now how can I find these swap files using `vimgrep` or terminal `grep`?

Answer (score 1):

Vim saves swap files in the same directory as the file you are editing by default. You should look there.

If you changed it in your `.vimrc` (or you downloaded someone else's), you should double check there to see if they are saved somewhere else. The option would go something like `set dir=~/.vim/swap`.

Once you determine where the swap files are likely to be found, we should go about recovering them. On a *nix system, they are hidden files (prepended with a `.`), and on DOS systems (Windows), it may be prepended with a = (but likely not hidden).

So, on a *nix system, the file you are looking for will look something like `myfile.swX`, where `myfile` is the name of the file you lost, and `X` may be any letter after `p` (vim renames swap files instead of deleting them).

To recover your file once you find it, open Vim, and run `:recover myfile.swp`.

Good luck, and I hope you find your files!

Comment: This is not what I asked for.

Comment: (Vim)grep is not uses to find files. It is used to search for matching text in files.   The locate(1) program may be of assistance, as it is designed to search the FS for files. Also see find(1) for searching the directory tree.

Comment: @shinokada, but that's what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `grep` for this, as the Vim swap files can already be identified by its *file extension*. Start a search with `find` from the base directory that contains all your opened Vim files, or the directory you've configured as `:set directory=...`:

```
$ find . -name '.*.swp'
```

PS: As `:vimgrep` opens the files in Vim itself, it probably cannot handle its own swapfiles.